# Create a blacklist

Tags: spamassassin, blacklist, amavis

I have installed postfix, amavisd, spamassassin and clamd. I want to specify a sender to blacklist. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

In your Spamassassin local.cf file (usually located in /etc/mail/spamassassin) add the following line:

```
blacklist_from <person you wish to blacklist.  wildcards are acceptable>
```

You can get more information on Spamassassin whitelist/blacklist [here](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/ManualWhitelist)
Restart spamassassin when you are done.

Answer (score -1):

Use DNSBL? Like spamhaus, spews or many others around. I am sure Postfix can reject email based on DNSBLs or local blacklists (I use `exim`, so I cannot give you specific instructions for Postfix).